# Reusing security rules defined by @Security annotation

Tags: php, security, symfony

Is it possible to check if user has access to a controller from outside of controller itself when permissions defined by `@Security` annotation?
For example:
If we have such a controller:

```
/**
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
*/
function myController() { ... }
```

Can we perform authorization check something like this:

*[pseudocode]*

```
    // get an object representation of `@Security` annotation
    $controllerSecurity = $this->get('some_magic_service')
        ->getSecurityForController('Bundle:Controller:myController');
   // check if a current user is granted
   if ($controllerSecurity->isGranted($user)) { ... }
```

*[/pseudocode]*

I think Symfony core security component does something similar when checks authorization for a controller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to check access for each route/controller, simply do not display your menu items for those that don't have access there. Create a service class that returns your user type.

services.yml

```
app_security.access.manager:
    class: AppBundle\Services\SecurityAccessManager
    arguments: [@security.authorization_checker,@security.token_storage]
```

SecurityAccessManager.php

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Services;


use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;

class SecurityAccessManager
{
    private $authorizationChecker;
    private $tokenStorage;   

    public function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker,TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;

    }


    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }


    public function isAdmin()
    {
        if($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') !== true) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }  

}
```

Then in your menu builder, you need to inject the class and to check rights:

This is an example with KNP menu:

```
app.menu.builder
        class: AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: [@knp_menu.factory,@medapp_security.access.manager]
```

And the menubuilder

```
class MenuBuilder extends ContainerAware
{
    /**
     * @var FactoryInterface
     */
    private $factoryInterface; 
    private $securityAccessManager;

   public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factoryInterface, SecurityAccessManager $securityAccessManager)
    {  
        $this->factoryInterface = $factoryInterface;   
        $this->securityAccessManager = $securityAccessManager;

    }
```

...

```
$menu->addChild('user link',..);
if ($this->securityAccessManager->isAdmin())     $menu->addChild('admin link',..);
```

Comment: I've eventually done quite the same thing =) It's enought to inject @service_container to MenuBuilder service and implement shortcut `isGranted` method there: 
`public function isGranted($attributes)
    {
        return $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted($attributes);
    }`

Comment: It is, but if later on you change your role you have to change it everywhere. However, if you use a custom class every time to check for it, if for some reason you do change the role later on you only have to change it from the custom class. Depends on what you're building.

Answer (score 0):

when **isGranted()** is called, it just use three standard Symfony2 Voters (+ custom Voters, if you have defined it): **AuthenticatedVoter**, **ExpressionVoter** and **RoleHierarchyVoter**.

AuthenticatedVoter simply checks current token authenticated level: **IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY**, **IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED** or **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY**.

So if you don't use Roles, only AuthenticatedVoter returns result by default.

If you want to define custom permissions for any action of controller, you can use [Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html). I think it most suitable for your task.

Then you can call Voters in the top of any action like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('permission', $entity);
    // your code
}
```

But if you want to apply security restrictions to whole section of an app, you can use [access_control](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html).

Comment: Thanks. I need check whether a user has access to a controller or not outside the controller itself and without duplication all the access rules defined in the controller. I need it for checking access for menu items while building a menu. I have there just a route name and a user object and should to check whether user has access to the controller (which can be easily retrieved by the route name)

Comment: And this @Security annotation seems to be a good place to keep reusable access rules

Comment: Looks like I can't understand what you're really need. If you want apply @Security to whole controller, you can do this.

Comment: He wants to to check permissions to other controllers from a custom class. He wants to build a menu and not display, for instance, link to admin panel on the menu, if the admin doesn't have admin rights to go to that link. I think?

Comment: The problem is that I have 4 user roles in the project and also have many controllers in it. For now all the security checks are performed by `denyAccessUnlessGranted` method (by custom voters or by simply `RoleHierarchyVoter`). So, some of the controllers are accessible only for specific roles. I also have a menu with items that point at that controllers. And I need to filter the items that not accessible to a current user. And this filtration is of course based on the same security checks as in the controllers. I just don't want to duplicate this cheks one again during filtering.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Yes, exactly!

Comment: I think, you can define controllers as services and then checks it permissions from separate class. something like `$this->get('service')->getController('controller')->isGranted($user);` But I'm not sure, I'm trying to get some information about.

Comment: looks like I'm right, but I think, that answer of @GeorgeIrimiciuc is the best way.